# How to detect Spam Bot list on magento 2

Tags: magento2, spam

I've found [this module](https://firebearstudio.com/blog/magento-2-spam-and-bot-blocker.html) which prevent spam bot on magento 2.

But i've a question: i don't know how this ***spam bot list*** work.

How do we know what's the name of the spam bot and put it in this list so this feature can do the job?

In other words, how do we detect the spam bot list?

Thanks for reading. Have a nice day.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it.
We can detect the spam bot with ***user-agent***.

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\HTTP\Header $httpHeader
) {
    $this->httpHeader = $httpHeader;
}

$userAgent = $this->httpHeader->getHttpUserAgent();
```

Ex: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html), then Googlebot is the spam bot we've detected.

I've found the answer in [this link](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/change-user-agent/368448/#close)